# Cast Java array of arrays to Java 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, casting

I have an object that is of type `Object[]`. All elements of the array are actually `Object[]` objects. So essentially it looks like this

```
Object[] oneD = {objectArray1, objectArray2, objectArray3, ...}
```

I want to cast this to an `Object[][]`, like this:

```
Object[][] twoD = (Object[][])oneD;
```

but I get compiler errors and `ClassCastException`'s.

Is there a (correct) way to do this?

Comment: yes, declare it as `Object[][] asdf`.

Comment: I'm not declaring it; it's being returned from a method. For more context, I have a method that operates on 1D arrays and I want to pass in a couple of 2D arrays and just have it operate on their first dimension.

Comment: Don't. Create a new method instead, that handles 2d arrays, and have it pass the 1st dimension to the original method.

Comment: Yes, I could copy and paste the 1D method into a second method that handles 2D arrays and move on. But what I'm looking for is a better solution than that.

Comment: This **is** a better solution than what you're suggesting. You're trying to force the same method to handle two types of arrays. That's a bad pattern!

Comment: A method that operates on arrays should be able to handle arrays of arrays just fine. Anyway, my main objective is to learn what alternative ways exist and to discover more about Java.

Comment: "A method that operates on arrays should be able to handle arrays of arrays just fine." not true. In Java `Object[]` and `Object[][]` are considered two *different* types.

Comment: @ alfasin This is the last comment I'm going to post on this question. Yes, those are different types. What I mean is that when I write a method, I want to be applicable to more than just 1 case. In my particular application, it is nicer to have a method that allows both 1D and 2D arrays to be passed in. It makes more sense to code it in this way than it does to make a separate method to handle the 2D case. I appreciate your willingness to give your opinions/suggestions. @Bohemian thanks for the edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't cast between array types - java ain't C, but you can transform one pretty easily:

```
Object[] oneD = {new Object[]{}, new Object[]{}, ...};
Object[][] twoD = Arrays.stream(oneD).map(Object[].class::cast).toArray(Object[][]::new);
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed. Take all the elements of `asdf`, cast them to `Object[]` objects, and then put them all into an `Object[][]`. Brilliant solution.

Answer (score 1):

Simply as

```
    String [] a = {"a", "b"}; 
    String [] b = {"c", "d"}; 

    String [][] ab = {a,b};
```

Comment: I think OP has an `Object[]` with an arbitrary number of elements, each of which is `Object[]`, handed to him and wants to address it as a `Object[][]`. So he can't code it up like this.

Comment: so I should vote to close this question as `unclear`

Comment: I'm asking about _casting_ or _converting_ an `Object[]` to an `Object[][]`, not _instantiating_ an `Object[][]`.

Comment: I think it is clear, and can be [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42080008/256196)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the inner Object arrays have the same size, you can do it this way:

```
    Object[] asdf = {new Object[3], new Object[3], new Object[3]};
    Object[][] newAsdf = {{asdf[0]}, {asdf[1]}, {asdf[2]}};
```

Comment: Except OP doesn't know how many elements are in `asdf`, so this code isn't useful.